# How to write a multidimensional array into separate files and then read from them in order in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to take a file, read the file into my program and split it into characters, split the resulting character array into a multidimensional array of 5,000 characters each, then write each separate array into a file found in the same location.

I have taken a file, read it, and created the multidimensional array. Now I want to write each separate single dimension array into separate files.

The file is obtained via user input. Then I created a chain helper method that stores the file to an array in the first mixin, this is then passed to another method that breaks it down into a multidimensional array, which finally hands it off to the end of the chain which currently is setup to make a new directory for which I will put these files.

```
require 'Benchmark/ips'

file = "C:\\test.php"
class String
  def file_to_array
    file = self
    return_file = File.open(file) do |line|
      line.each_char.to_a
    end
    return return_file
  end
  def file_write
    file_to_write = self
    if Dir.exist?("I:\\file_to_array")
      File.open("I:/file_to_array/tmp.txt", "w") { |file| file.write(file_to_write) }
      read_file = File.read("I:/file_to_array/tmp.txt")
    else
      Dir.mkdir("I:\\file_to_array")
    end
  end
end

class Array
  def file_divider
    file_to_divide = self
    file_to_separate = []
    count = 0
    while count != file_to_divide.length
      separator = count % 5000
      if separator == 0
        start = count - 5000
        stop = count
        file_to_separate << file_to_divide[start..stop]
      end
      count = count + 1
    end
    return file_to_separate
  end
  def file_write
    file_to_write = self
    if Dir.exist?("I:\\file_to_array")
      File.open("I:/file_to_array/tmp.txt", "w") { |file| file.write(file_to_write) }
    else
      Dir.mkdir("I:\\file_to_array")
    end
  end
end
Benchmark.ips do |result|
  result.report { file.file_to_array.file_divider.file_write }
end
```

Test.php

```
<?php
echo "hello world"
?>
```

Comment: I would suggest not to monkeypatch the core classes. Just have a class that encapsulates your business logic. It would make your  code more readable.
Also, `String` in ruby can already be treated as an array. So, just split your string from the file into strings of 5000 chars and write them to a file as shown below.

Comment: Would putting it in a Class prevent the String and Array Handling errors?

Comment: Did not understand the question. Your code can handle any errors, right?

Comment: I monkey patched because those functions caused conversion errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This untested code is where I'd start to split text into chunks and save it:

```
str = "I want to take a file"

str_array = str.scan(/.{1,10}/) # => ["I want to ", "take a fil", "e"]

str_array.each.with_index(1) do |str_chunk, i|
  File.write("output#{i}", str_chunk)
end
```

This doesn't honor word-boundaries.

Reading a separate input file is easy; You can use `read` if you KNOW the input will never exceed the available memory and you don't care about performance.

Thinking about it further, if you want to read a text file and break its contents into smaller files, then read it in chunks:

```
input = File.open('input.txt', 'r')
i = 1
until input.eof? do
  chunk = input.read(10)
  File.write("output#{i}", chunk)
  i += 1
end
input.close
```

Or even better because it automatically closes the input:

```
File.open('input.txt', 'r') do |input|
  i = 1
  until input.eof? do
    chunk = File.read(10)
    File.write("output#{i}", chunk)
    i += 1
  end
end
```

Those are not tested but it look about right.

Comment: Now that's incredibly useful.

Comment: I would just have to use the regular expression to capture the word boundaries as well. I hadn't thought of doing it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use standard [File](http://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html) API and [Serialisation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html).

```
File.write('path/to/yourfile.txt', Marshal.dump([1, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: I have added the code to demonstrate what is happening.